# How to get single image source from multiple image source

Tags: php

I get this type of array:

```
    $data = array (
    $imageData => array (
        0 => array (
          'id' => 2224689676,
          'product_id' => 56286180,
          'position' => 1,
          'src' => '87643-674-1.jpg?v=1521829158',
          'variant_ids' => array (),
        ),
        1 => array (
          'id' => 50653369,
          'product_id' => 56286180,
          'position' => 2,
          'src' => 'https://pro.PNG?v=1537789170',
          'variant_ids' => array (0 => 7137761),
        ),
        2 => array (
          'id' => 506533950,
          'product_id' => 56286180,
          'position' => 3,
          'src' => 'product_description.PNG?v=1537789191',
          'variant_ids' => array (
            0 => 7137761,
          ),
        ),
        3 => array (
          'id' => 508279531,
          'product_id' => 56286180,
          'position' => 6,
          'src' => 'Untitled.png?v=1537865220',
          'variant_ids' => array (
             0 => 7137761,
             1 => 71377617
           ),
        ),
    ),
);
```

And I want to display `src` of real index when variant `count > 0` otherwise `src` of `[0]` index display. Note: one image have multiple variant `ids`.

I am trying this code:

```
$images=array_column($data,'imageData');

$image1=[];
foreach ($images as $image)
{
    $imageData = array_column($image, 'variant_ids');
    $imageSrc = array_column($image, 'src');
    if (count($imageData) > 0)
    {
        $image1[]=$image;
    }
    $image1 = $imageSrc[0];
}
```

I want to get this type of output:

```
$image = array(0=> array(7137761 =>"Untitled.png?v=1537865220"),
               1=>array(71377617 => "Untitled.png?v=1537865220"),
               2=>array(7137761=>"product_description.PNG?v=1537789191"),
            if array emtpty so 
            3=>87643-674-1.jpg?v=1521829158
            );
```

Comment: If you have resolved your problem, mark one answer as correct or mark question as solved

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($data['imageData'] as $image)
{
  if(count($image['variant_ids'])>0)
      foreach($image['variant_ids'] as $variant)
          $result[] = array($variant => $image['src']);
  else
      $result[] = $image['src'];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an unexpected output, try to print_r the arrays.

However:

> $imageSrc is not an array, so it does not have element 0
>
> You need to have an else statement, if not so the code after the if is always executed, moreover $image1 = $imageSrc is overriding $image1 whole content

Anyway, this code should work:

```
$images = $data['imageData'];

$imagesWithVariants=[];
foreach ($images as $image)
{
    $imageData = $image['variant_ids'];
    $imageSrc = $image['src'];
    if (count($imageData) > 0)
    {
        $imagesWithVariants[]=array($imageData[0] => $imageSrc);
    }else{
        $imagesWithVariants[]=$imageSrc;
    }

}

print_r($imagesWithVariants);
```

If you want a default value for $imgSrc, instead, you need to get it before the loop:

```
$defaultImgSrc = $images[0]['src'];

foreach(....){
  .
  .
  .
  if(...){
    .
    .
  }else{
     $imagesWithVariants[]=$defaultImgSrc;
  }
}
```

> ***array_column*** is not intended to be used in for loop, here you can check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php)

An example using array_column:

```
$images = $data['imageData'];

$imagesWithVariants=[];

$imageData = array_column($images,'variant_ids');
$imageSrc = array_column($images,'src');



foreach($imageData as $key=>$data){
    if(count($data) > 0){
        $imagesWithVariants[]= array($data[0]=>$imageSrc[$key]);
    }else{
        $imagesWithVariants[]=$imageSrc[0];
    }
}

print_r($imagesWithVariants);
```

***EDIT:***

Obviously, if you have more than one variants and you want them all, you need a foreach on variants:

```
if(count($data) > 0){
   foreach($data as $variant_id){
     $imagesWithVariants[]= array($variant_id=>$imageSrc);
   }
}
```